# auto coords in lemon .eps exporting

Tags: c++, graph, coordinates, eps, lemon-graph-library

In Lemon tutorial all examples specify coords when drawing graph:

```
graphToEps(g,"graph_to_eps_demo_out_1_pure.eps").
    coords(coords).
    title("Sample .eps figure").
    copyright("(C) 2003-2009 LEMON Project").
    run();
```

Is there any possibility to export image of a graph to .eps file (or any other) without specifying coords? (I mean autoarrangement)